# Return value after asynchronou IndexedDb call is finished in function in angularJS (custom filter)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, return-value, indexeddb

I write my custom AngularJS filter, which should transform id to name, which will get from IndexedDb.
I wrote this filter:

```
cardsList.filter('getCollectionName', ['IndexedDb', function(IndexedDb) {
return function(idCollection) {
    var val = 'not';
    IndexedDb.getById(IndexedDb.STORES.COLLECTION_STORE, idCollection).then(function(data) {
        val = data.name;    //here dont work return data.name;
    }, function(err){
        $window.alert(err);
    });
   return val; // here is still 'not'
};  }]);
```

So i have property val and i want set it with name of collection by id. But its return initial value 'not'.
I knew that inside calling is not visible property val. But return data.name; inside succesful callback dont work.
I looked at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), but I dont understood how fix my problem.
How can I fix this so function return data.name from callback? Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can use $q service of the angularjs.
Return the value when your promise resolves in $q.all(..)

```
cardsList.filter('getCollectionName', ['IndexedDb','$q', function(IndexedDb,$q) {
return function(idCollection) {
    var val = 'not';
    var promises=[];
    promises.push(IndexedDb.getById(IndexedDb.STORES.COLLECTION_STORE,idCollection).then(function(data) {
         val = data.name;    //here dont work return data.name;
         }, function(err){
           $window.alert(err);
        })
    );


    $q.all(promises).then(function(){return val;});
};  }]);
```

Comment: Its looks well, but if I edited my code like this. Filter dont work (dont replace idCollection by return val.
I needed return that value from ' this: return function(idCollection) { ' function.
if I do var pom = $q.all(promises).then(... then I have in var pom: Promise object with that value, but i dont know how access to Promise->$$state->value  (console log in chrome)

Comment: And Why I need $q.all()? its push to array only one promise.

Comment: It is like if you are waiting on multiple promises, you can push those to the promises array and $q.all is wait on all that promises.

Comment: And for your above comment, why dont try and use simple function, instead of filter.

Comment: Because I print data in template using ng-repeat, and for item I acces to collectionId. From that i need get name of collection. So i thought that filter is right for this situation? But I dont know how get/return value from that promise.
And i dont store collection information to this item, when I need this information only on one place.

Comment: Out of all it is not advisable to make ajax request for each item in ng-repeat, it will take lot of time to load on every model change.
You can pre fetch the data and store it in model and then use that data inn ng-repeat.

Comment: Yea, but with fetch another data to model I have similar problem.
How get data from out of this function :
IndexedDb.getById(IndexedDb.STORES.COLLECTION_STORE,idCollection).then(function(data) {
         val = data.name;    //here dont work return data.name;
         },

Comment: Or exist any posibbilities how work with it synchronously?